Given a commutative ring $R$ and an element $a \in R$ construct a new ring in which a becomes invertible

Hello all. I'm working my way through this problem for my algebra class and I'm currently having difficulty with part E. I've managed to solve every other part of this problem, most importantly D. From D we can conclude that any ring such that epsilon is not injective cannot be a domain.
The only examples of commutative rings that are not domains that I can recall are Z/nZ for n not prime. So rings like Z/4Z and Z/6Z are the best candidates that I'm aware of.
Beyond this I don't know how to proceed I've tried looking at Z/4Z[x]/(2x-1) and trying to show that the kernel of epsilon is non-zero but I cannot come up with anything.
Any and all help is appreciated :)

Note that in $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[x]$ we have $(2x-1)^2=4x^2-4x+1=1$, and so the constant polynomial $1$ is a multiple of $2x-1$, which means the element $1$ belongs to the kernel.

Feels so obvious now that I'm looking at it lol. Thanks for the help sir!

In your example $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[x]/(2x-1)$ we have $2x=1$ and $2\cdot 2=0$, thus $2=2\cdot 1=2\cdot 2\cdot x=0$ and thus $1=2x=0$, thus it is the zero ring.

Really cool insight. Thank you!

@Norftopia Was it not obvious that zero-divisors (e.g. nilpotents) are never units (invertibles) (except possibly in the zero ring, depending on definitions).
